# Android Studio Share Icon doesn't appear in my other activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

Hi I am trying to implement a share button in my action bar on another view in my other activity. I can see the button being implemented in my preview, however when I run it it doesn't show up. However, the settings icon shows up (even though I deleted it, and when I click it a drop down comes down and when I click it, it works as my share button.

here is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".BlogWebViewActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share_dark"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_share">
    </item>
</menu>
```

![menuview]http://i692.photobucket.com/albums/vv287/kkmoslehpour/layout-2014-09-27-224803_zpse6426bf8.png

But when I run it in the emulator it still shows the settings icon. I am running it using genymotion, I have also tried running it in the android emulator as well still the same.
I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding the project. Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Are you definitely referring to the correct menu xml file in your onCreateOptionsMenu method? It sounds like there is a default menu being shown _as well as_ your custom menu, and your click listener for the entire menu is set up to share (which is why the settings options appears to be performing a share action also).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you override these methods: `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

Also, if you are implementing this in a fragment, make sure you have `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` somewhere in your code. I normally have it under `onActivityCreated` to make sure it is enabled after the activity is created.

Comment: those methods have been overridden already, however, i am still getting the same issue. I see the settings icon instead of the share icon, but in my preview i see the share icon.

Comment: The preview will only show the current many. However, in reality you may have stacked menus, for example: Normally an activity will have the settings menu item. Then if you have fragments with their own menu items e.g. a share menu item, then those will be appended. But you will only see the settings menu from the activity unless you have setOptionsMenu(true) in the fragment.
That's what I think is happening.